# Query Tuning with Different Disaggregations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Is there any possibility where in I can reduce the number of queries and implement the below different disaggregations in a single query? The table accessed is huge and contain millions of records. So I trying to optimize the query so that I do not have to access the same table multiple times!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `rollup` or grouping sets.  I think this may come close to what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 'Chicago' AS Region, District, SchoolName AS School, Category ,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ssid) AS Total ,
       SUM(DirectEnroll) AS Met
FROM final.NSC_Analysis
WHERE  GradYear = 2013
GROUP BY Category, Schoolname, District WITH rollup;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work for the `count(distinct)` in SQL Server prior to 2008.

Comment: @BenThul . . . Once upon a time, SQL Server didn't roll up count distinct  correctly.  Now it does.  But one gets into habits of being careful, so one forgets exactly about which versions work and do not work.  But it now works.

Comment: @Shyam . . . I am not sure what your comment means.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.  `group by A, B, C` means `group by A, B, C` -- all distinct combinations of the three columns are in the result set exactly once.